# jTextField autocomplete from database

Tags: java, database, swing, autocomplete

I want a jTextField that shows suggestions in a popup as the user types (like google suggests). I want suggestions data to be fetched from a database table. I have been looking at SwingX and GlazedLists but I think they provide jComboBox autocomplete, and jTextField does not show a popup in these libraries.

I want to monitor user input and re-query the database after specific intervals.

Thanks.

Comment: "I want ..".  I want a pony.  But besides announcing our wish lists, did you have a question?

Comment: Does this not look like a question to you? Strange !!!

Comment: And instead of just criticizing, wouldn't it much better if you had posted an answer to my question?

Comment: in defense of Andrew:  You aren't really asking any questions.  You are listing features needed.  I would suggest adding a sentence to the effect of "How can I construct an I control that meets this criteria?".   That why it is more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep looking into SwingX or GlazedLists, to avoid re-inventing the wheel. But if you are doing it yourself:

Add a `KeyListener` to the field and show a popup just below the text field whenever the user types.  The popup could just be a menu with possible items or maybe even a `JList`.  Make sure your database query can keep up with the typing or put the work on a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks jzd, I'll try add KeyListener as you suggested